# How to force recomposition of AndroidView?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Disclaimer: I have seen many similar questions posted already. However in all those questions, they were not aware of the `update` parameter to `AndroidView`. I am aware of the `update` parameter.

#### The problem

I have a legacy `CustomView` that has two methods to set its data. Let's call them `setDataSlow()` and `setDataFast()`.

The `setDataSlow()` method is expected to be called only once in the lifetime of the view, and it is relatively slow.

The `setDataFast()` method needs to be called frequently, and is very fast.

So, the natural code in Compose would be something like this:

```kotlin
var data1 by remember {mutableStateOf(0)}
var data2 by remember {mutableStateOf(0)}

AndroidView(factory = {
    val v = CustomView(it)
    v.setDataSlow(data1)
    v
  }, update = {
    it.setDataFast(data2)
  }
)
```

The problem is, the `factory` lambda gets only called once, even when `data1` changes. I understand this is by design.

#### Question

How do I solve this? If I call `setDataSlow()` inside `update`, it will slow down the UI tremendously.

I need to somehow force the `factory` method to update, and the only way I can do that is to force recompose of `AndroidView` somehow.

Comment: you need to call `setDataSlow` each time `data1` is changed, but don't wanna call it when only `data2` is changed, right? The simplest way is check whether `data1` is really changed before performing any heavy operations, you can do this either on Compose part or inside `setDataSlow` (I find the second one more preferable). You can wrap android view with `key(data1)`, but this is gonna create a new view - I think it's redundant if you can just check whether the data was changed.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov That's exactly what I ended up doing! Thanks for confirming the validity of my approach. In reality, it was a little tricky because data1 wasn't a nice integer variable, and there were many views and threads involved requiring synchronization, but the gist of it was exactly as you described: check for `data1 === prevData1` inside `setDataSlow`.